# TypeError: PrimeFaces.Locales is undefined

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Im working on an evolutive maintenance software so my code and dependencies are somewhat outdated. Im using PrimeFaces 2.2.1, JSF 2.0, Hybernate to show a primefaces schedule. What i was trying to do is to overwrite on my xhtml page the PrimeFaces.Locales object but i keep receiving "TypeError: PrimeFaces.Locales is undefined" on my Firefox.

**This is my AgendaCalendario.xhtml**

```
<ui:fragment xml:lang="pt-BR" lang="pt-BR"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['agenda.label.calendario']}"/>
    </legend>

    <h:panelGrid id="filtroMesAno" columns="7" styleClass="tabelaEspacada            FormLineButtons">

        <!-- Filtro Mês  -->
        <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['generico.label.mes']}"   for="mesFilter"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="mesFilter"
                         style="min-width: 80px; width: 100px;"
                         value="#   {agendaCalendarioManagedBean.entradaAgendaFilter.mesDoAnoEnum}"
                         converter="mesesDoAnoEnumConverter">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{i18n['br.com.petrobras.fcorp.combo.noselection']}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.mesesDoAnoEnumList}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <!-- Filtro Ano -->
        <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['generico.label.ano']}" for="anoFilter"/>
        <h:inputText id="anoFilter" value="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.entradaAgendaFilter.ano}"
                     onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);"
                     maxlength="4" style="min-width: 15px; width: 28px; margin-right: 5px !important;"/>

        <!-- Botão Pesquisar -->
        <h:commandButton id="filtroDataPesquisaButton"
                         styleClass="FormButtonAction"
                         style="margin: 0px 3px 5px 0; padding: 5px 5px 5px    5px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                         border:solid 1px #CCC; vertical-align: bottom;"
                         action="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.aplicarFiltroData}"
                         onclick="waitPanel.show();"
                         value="#{i18n['crud.button.pesquisar']}"/>

        <!-- div de espaçamento -->
        <t:div styleClass="space-330"></t:div>

        <!-- Legenda da Agenda -->
        <t:div styleClass="floatRight">
            <ui:include src="/pages/interno/Agenda/AgendaLegenda.xhtml"/>
        </t:div>
    </h:panelGrid>

<script type="text/javascript">
    PrimeFaces.Locales['pt'] = {
            month: 'Mês',
            week: 'Semana'
    }
</script>

    <p:schedule id="calendario" value="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.scheduleManagedBean}"
                dateSelectListener="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.onDateSelect}"
                onDateSelectStart="waitPanel.show();"
                eventSelectListener="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.onEventSelect}"
                onEventSelectStart="waitPanel.show();"
                initialDate="#{agendaCalendarioManagedBean.entradaAgendaFilter.initialDateToCalendar}"
                editable="true"
                locale="pt"
                draggable="false"
                resizable="false"
                view="month"
                leftHeaderTemplate="title"
                centerHeaderTemplate="prev, today, next"
                rightHeaderTemplate="month, basicWeek"
                onEventSelectUpdate="agendaMsgError"/>
    </fieldset>
</ui:fragment>
```

My java library contains the right files (JSF, Primefaces etc), my presentation.xml contains the tags for the LazyScheduleManagedBean and in other parts of the application everything works fine. Plz any tip ll help, if in need i can provide more details. Thank u all.

Comment: How exactly are you sure that `PrimeFaces.Locales` is supported in 2.2.1? It's in 2.2.1 users guide?

Comment: Well Balus there at the PrimeFaces docs u ll see that locales is supported and there are some minor details for schedule config and customization. I was trying to use the columnFormat property on the <p:schedule ...> tag for editing the column headers, with no luck. I searched extensivily the net and found no concrete answers for why it isnt working, found as well some hacks but was not interested. So im now trying this other method but javascript cant find a PrimeFaces definition.